# RegexpTokenizer syntax $[\d\.]?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am looking at this example

```
>>> tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+')
>>> tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\w+|\$[\d\.]+')
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(s)
['Good', 'muffins', 'cost', '$3.88', 'in', 'New', 'York', 'Please', 'buy', 'me', 'two', 'of', 'them', 'Thanks']
>>> tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+')
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(s)
['Good', 'muffins', 'cost', '$3.88', 'in', 'New', 'York', '.', 'Please', 'buy', 'me', 'two', 'of', 'them', '.', 'Thanks', '.']
```

Is there any difference between `RegexpTokenizer` syntax and Python regular expressions? For example, what does:

```
$[\d\.]
```

stand for? From [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) we learn that `\d` matches any decimal digit.

Comment: Do you mean the [NLTK `RegexpTokenizer`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=regexptokenizer#nltk.tokenize.regexp.RegexpTokenizer)? Do you have a reason to think they're using a different regex syntax to `re` (and every other language that uses the standard syntax)? It seems pretty unlikely you'd use some other syntax and still call it regex, as that would lead to enormous confusion.

Comment: @jonsharpe kudos to linking the uber duped thread!!